# Firefox: padding-bottom not showing up in fixed positioned element with overflow: scroll on flex container

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox

The problem is that padding-bottom is not displayed in Firefox.

Margin-bottom in the child element has no effect if container has display property with the flex value. (display: block is ok.)

It happens only in Firefox. In other browsers padding-bottom on the ancestor and margin-bottom appears on the descendant.

Tell me please, why this is happening. I have read the specification, but could not find the answer.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdeOzy?editors=1100

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="modal">
        <b>[BEGIN]</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit ... <b>[END]</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    padding: 20px; /* padding-bottom is not displayed in FF */
    overflow-y: scroll;

    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.modal {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;

    /* in the FF it works only when .wrap element
       has display property with block value, not flex */
    /* margin-bottom: 20px; */

    padding: 20px;

    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: **is there any reasons why you want `display:flex;` on wrapper ?**

Comment: I used this property just for the vertical alignment of the child element.
P.S. I can solve the problem simply by adding another element to it, and assign padding. My question is not how to do it, I wanted to know the reason for such behavior.

Comment: well margin:auto; allow overflow of child flex to be visible , but it only  overflows. if you set align-items and justify-content to parent instead margin:auto; behavior is not coherent, it is different when you would expect to behave the same :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONxdGj?editors=1100  flex-child has to overflow somehow and still inherit some flex-basis defaut values somehow :) You have side effects and i'm not so sure that FF misbehave . child flex could  be the one showing a scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, this was a very peculiar bug... I haven't seen that before. It seems that the problem lies in bad overlapping of the elements when your modal element doesn't cooperate very well with the wrapper. It can be fixed by modifying the CSS in the following way:

```
.wrap{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
.modal{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It still happens even not for fixed elements, but for any scrollable flex containers.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.flex-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min(500px, 100%);
  height: min(500px, 100vh);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header, .footer {
  flex: 0 auto;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #bed;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 auto;
  padding: 40px 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-layout">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    This block looks good in Chrome. Just try to scroll it until end. There is should be a padding in the bottom between text and footer.
<br><br>
But in Firefox no padding if content overflowing with scroll.
<br><br>
    What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```